# AES get different results by using the same key and iv to encrypt the same plaintext repeatedly

Tags: python, encryption, aes, pycrypto, cbc-mode

Here is my code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import binascii

def encrypt(secret_key, sign, raw):
    key = md5(secret_key).hexdigest()[::-2]
    iv = md5(sign).hexdigest()[::-2]
    raw += (16 - len(raw) % 16) * '\0'
    generator = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)

    #***********************************************
    #Problems occur at here ! 
    #If I execute "generator.encrypt(raw)"
    #The results are not same every time

    print generator.encrypt(raw) # result_1
    print generator.encrypt(raw) # result_2
    print generator.encrypt(raw) # result_3

    #***********************************************

    return binascii.b2a_hex(generator.encrypt(raw))
```

I will get the different results when every time I execute "generator.encrypt(raw)"
It is very confuse to me because I used the same KEY and IV.

I want to establish a API-SYSTEM, I need others post their cryptographic data no matter which language they used, just want to get the same result in AES.

How can I get the stable result in using AES?

I mean I want to get the same result when I using the same KEY and IV to encrypt the same plaintext.

Comment: Somewhere, your IV is being re-initialized. This happened with me in Golang AES implementation. You'll need to go through the docs to see what each step does.

Comment: change AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv) to generator = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv) and see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AES` implementation in pycrypto is stateful for CBC mode. This statefulness can be simulated by the IV value. Let's assume that `raw` is shorter than 16 bytes for simplicity.

In that case the code

```
raw += (16 - len(raw) % 16) * '\0' # zero padding
generator = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)

print generator.encrypt(raw) # result_1
print generator.encrypt(raw) # result_2
print generator.encrypt(raw) # result_3
```

is equivalent to

```
raw += (16 - len(raw) % 16) * '\0' # zero padding
generator = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)
ct1 = generator.encrypt(raw) 
print ct1 # result_1

generator = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=ct1)
ct2 = generator.encrypt(raw) 
print ct2 # result_2

generator = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=ct2)
ct3 = generator.encrypt(raw) 
print ct3 # result_3
```

The reason is that the IV is advanced internally according to the definition of the [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29). It means that the IV is set to the last full ciphertext block.

If `raw` is assumed to be any length, then the following would be equivalent where only the last block of the ciphertext is used as the IV for the next encryption:

```
raw += (16 - len(raw) % 16) * '\0' # zero padding
generator = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)
ct1 = generator.encrypt(raw) 
print ct1 # result_1

generator = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=ct1[-16:])
ct2 = generator.encrypt(raw) 
print ct2 # result_2

generator = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=ct2[-16:])
ct3 = generator.encrypt(raw) 
print ct3 # result_3
```

**If you don't want that, then you need to initialize the `generator` with the original IV.**